# How to connect my wordpress newsletter form to civiCRM?

Tags: wordpress, forms, newsletter, form-snippets

I need some help with connecting my wordpress newsletter form to civiCRM. I’ve just started using civiCRM and I want to connect the sign up form ( that I aready have in wordpress) with civiCRM, so that when contacts sign up for my newsletter in my page, it gets added in my lists in civicRM.

Comment: Welcome Dea!  You can help us help you by editing your question to add more info.  What plugin are you using for your newsletter signup form?  What's the service you use to send the mail?  Also - typically it works the other way around, you create a newsletter form in CiviCRM, then that sends the data to your newsletter service - but if you share more info maybe someone will have a solution.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech Thank you for replying, Im sorry Im new to all of this and Im trying to do everything on my own due to low budget.Service for sending mail is sendgrid My newsletter form in CiviCRM I can create it in Profiles, right? And how to I send data to my newsletter service? Isn't there some type of code in civicrm so I can implement it in wordpress?

Comment: It's a bit confusing to understand your setup, so there's a limit to how much DIY assistance you'll get.  Also - are you saying you construct your newsletter's content on Sendgrid.com?  That's pretty unusual - most people use Sendgrid as a pass-through for another service (e.g. CiviMail).  You can use profiles to let people sign up and their data will be entered in CiviCRM, but if you already have a form submitting that data to Sendgrid, you can't combine the features of both forms into a single form without custom code, which you want to avoid.

Comment: Various ways to approach this depending on requirements and what you want to achieve. You can use a CiviCRM profile and expose that via a shortcode on a page. Or you can use the Form Processor extension which I think can integrate with a form made using something like the Contact Form 7 plugin in WP.

Answer (score 0):

you will need a 'connector' between WordPress and CiviCRM. Depending on if CiviCRM is installed within the Wordpress website or installed seperately, the way to connect will be different. If they are independent then you need a tool such as CiviMcRestFace. The inlay extensions pack can also be an alternative to expose a newsletter subscribe form on an external website and register the contact in CiviCRM.

You might need to change the form builder you use in Wordpress to tools that are compatible with CiviCRM. Actually there are different ways of setting this up.